# Exception after import from new folder in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have been trying to add new folder in app. Lets say I already have component A and B.
I create new folder app/test. In the folder I create test-component.ts and I import it in component A. 
I am now getting EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component

In test-component.ts I use component B.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try and use something like this.

```
Import {MyComponent} from './app/project/my-component'
```

Its working for me i have pasted my directive.ts in a Directive folder and i have registered it to app.module.ts as

```
import { HighlightDirective } from './directive/highlight.directive'
```

Make sure you are using single quotes that can be a issue some times.

Comment: I did. Before that it was exception not found

Comment: Now it works with the same code :) Really don't know what happened yesterday